# Team City publish unit test results to artifacts

Tags: teamcity, artifacts

How can we publish the unit test results from the tests to artifacts? in HTM and XML formats? 
I tried adding this '
General Settings/Artifacts Paths: 
testresults.* => testresults.zip

In Build steps, I am using .NET CLI (dotnet) as Runner type

Please help!

Comment: what command are you using to run the unit tests? Is there an argument or option you could add, specifying the location?

Answer (score 0):

In the command line you could use the following `dotnet test -l:trx;LogFileName=TestOutput.xml`, but TeamCity replaces the default logger by its own logger to provides the integration and the real-time feedback. You can prevent TeamCity to replace the default logger by adding the configuration parameter `dotnet.cli.test.reporting=Off`, please take in account that TeamCity has no test report in this scenario.

So to achieve your goals:

- add the configuration parameter `dotnet.cli.test.reporting=Off` for your build configuration or a project
- add the command line argument `-l:trx;LogFileName=TestOutput.xml` in the field `Command line parameters`
- specify `Artifact paths` as `**/TestOutput.xml => TestResults.zip`

Comment: does build step take into consideration, if we just add the configuration parameter for the dotnet.cli.test.reporting with its valu as off, or do we need to send that as a command line parameter in the build step